# Django Rest Framework custom user model creating instance along with nested object instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model 'Reader' which extends the default 'User' model:

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    wishlist_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Reader(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    # A library has many readers
    which_library = models.ForeignKey('Library', related_name='readers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wishlist = models.OneToOneField(Wishlist, null=True, blank=True)

    #This helps to print in admin interface
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.user)
```

**Question 1**: Can I directly create a Reader instead of User (without having to associated a reader to an existing User, which I currently see in my admin interface), and in that case how should my POST call look like? For registering new user currently I need Username, password1, password2.

**Question 2**: While creating a Reader I also want to create a Wishlist for that Reader. How to achieve that?

So far I have a serializer:

```
class ReaderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Reader
        fields = '__all__'
        #depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        wishlist_data = validated_data.pop('wishlist')
        reader = Reader.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Wishlist.objects.create(reader=reader, **wishlist_data)
        return reader
```

And a view:

```
# Get all readers in a specific library or create a new reader
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def reader_list(request, library_id):
    """
    List all readers in a specific library, or create a new reader for a specific library

    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        readers = Reader.objects.filter(which_library=library_id)
        print(readers)
        serializer = ReaderSerializer(readers, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ReaderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I thought my serializer would create a wishlist instance automatically but it doesn't.

Comment: what exactly is `wishlist` in your request?  Are you able to create a wishlist instance in the shell following the exact same steps?

Comment: My model relationships: A Reader (who is a User) will have one 'Wishlist' and a 'Wishlist' can have many 'Books'. I can not (and do not want to as well) create Wishlist without a Reader